# What is the eclipse java declaration shortcut?

Tags: java, eclipse

There´s any eclipse shortcut to stance a new object ?
For example. I would like to type:

```
Object zzz =
```

and it would complete for me this way:

```
Object zzz = new Object();
```

with void parameter of course.
I will wait answers.. thank you people.

Comment: "Object zzz = new O" then ctrl + Space should autocomplete that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the template 'new':

1) type new and then ctrl+space.

2) Choose the 'create new object' option

3) Insert the class name and parameters (if needed)

If you don't want the parameters, you can create a template yourself (preferences->java->editor->templates). Assign a unique name to it, and set the pattern to:

```
${type} ${name} = new ${type}();
```

Comment: Thank you, it´s very usefull. I didn´t know before.

Answer (score 4):

If you type `Object zzz = new`  and then <crtrl>+<space> that brings up intellisense, and you can just hit <enter> and you'll get the first available constructor.

Comment: Yes it worked friend but in my eclipse Ganymede it doesn´t put the () in the end.. its not very usefull I think.

Comment: Well, in Galileo it also gives you the parenthesis, so I guess it is time for you to upgrade ;) But seriously, how much work is it really to manually add ()..?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to write new Object() and then use the "Extract Local Variable" Refactoring (Alt + Shift + L), in cases where I need to pass in parameters to the constructor I find this works well.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse ships with a default template `new`.  To use it, type "new" then Ctrl-Space (or your autocomplete key sequence) and select "new - create new object."  You will then be prompted in-line to fill in the type, variable name and arguments.  Use tab to move to the next field.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut should be `Ctrl+Space` as other answers mentioned.

---

Another walk around for people who has it has assigned to other applications and don't want to(or don't know how to) modify it:

Change the default in Auto activation triggers for Java to `._abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`(note the white space after `Z`) for **content assist** in Preferences.

It may sometimes be annoying though, since it may pop up too frequently.

---

PS:
the `new` template and the `content assist` should be two different concepts.